# Evaluate $\int_{C}\dfrac{e^{z}}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz$ if C is a circle of radius 3 with centered at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

Note, i know that this question can be solved easily by residue theorem, however i want to solve it using Cauchy integral method.

Here is how i approached it, i tried to use partial fractions and get to the step $\int_{C}\dfrac{e^{z}}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz = \int_{C}\dfrac{-e}{z-1}dz + \int_{C}\dfrac{e^{2}}{z-2}dz$ and then i applied the CIF formula where i claim that $-e$ and $e^{2}$ is analytic everywhere on the circle $C$. Somehow i got the answer as needed, however i realized that i am not sure if a constant function can be analytic on the circle or not. So i think my approach may be flawed.

Here is the second approach which i do not understand, the answer decomposed to become $\int_{C}\dfrac{e^{z}}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz = \int_{C1}\dfrac{e^{z}}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz + \int_{C2}\dfrac{e^{z}}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz$ where he claimed $C1$ is the circle centered at 1 with radius 0.5 and $C2$ is the circle centered at 2 with radius 0.5. I do not know how this decomposition came about. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

let $f(z) = \frac{e^z}{(z-1)(z-2)}$, then we have $$\int_{C}f(z) = 2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^{n}Res_{z=z_k}f(z)$$
here $n=2, z_1=1,z_2=2$. and each pole is 1-order.

$$Res_{z=z_1}f(z) = \lim_{z \to 1}\frac{1}{(1-1)!}\frac{d^{1-1}(z-1)^1f(z)}{dz^{1-1}} = \lim_{z \to 1}\frac{e^z}{z-2} = -e$$
$$Res_{z=z_2}f(z) = \lim_{z \to 2}\frac{1}{(1-1)!}\frac{d^{1-1}(z-2)^1f(z)}{dz^{1-1}} = \lim_{z \to 2}\frac{e^z}{z-1} = e^2$$
so $$\int_{C}f(z) = 2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^{n}Res_{z=z_k}f(z) = 2\pi i(-e+e^2)$$

Comment: Hi would Like to mention that I wish not to use residue theorem here

Comment: Notice the first line in the question.

Comment: sorry, try again. let $C_1 := |z-1|=\varepsilon, C_2 := |z-2|=\varepsilon$. $f_1(z) = \frac{e^z}{z-2},a_1=1, f_2(z)=\frac{e^z}{z-1},a_2=2$. then $f_1(z)$ is analytic on $C_1$, $f_2(z)$ is analytic on $C_2$. by Cauchy ,$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_1}\frac{e^z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_1}\frac{f_1(z)}{z-a_1}dz = f_1(a_1)=-e$$, $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_2}\frac{e^z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz=e^2$.

Comment: @xunitc i do not understand why C1 + C2 gets you the C

Comment: @ilovewt by Cauchy-Goursat theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem maybe we need attention the direction of $C, C_1, C_2$.